# What is the best practice for implementing a Bootstrap 4 Split Navigation?

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4, navigation

Is there a better way to code a BS-4 split navigation than how I have coded the following. In a perfect world, I would want to have only one instance of each link, but I cannot figure out if there is a way to do it

https://jsfiddle.net/jpmoran/v8Larf2n/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            <span class="navbar-text h3 pb-0 mb-0">BizCards4Less</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block ml-auto">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Cart</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light shadow" style="background-color: #fff;">
        <div class="navbar-nav mx-md-auto w-100 d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-sm-center">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link h6 px-auto px-md-3 mx-md-3" href="#">Shop Biz Cards</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link h6 px-auto px-md-3 mx-md-3" href="#">Re-Order Program</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link h6 px-md-3 mx-md-3 d-none d-md-block" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link h6 px-md-3 mx-md-3 d-none d-md-block" href="#">Blog</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light d-md-none shadow">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Cart</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick with static HTML - **No**. HTML can not contain the logic that decides what nav items appear in either the dropdown, then bar, or both without code repetition.

With complex CSS through @media queries (bootstrap 4's ".hidden-..." classes) - **Sort of**.

With JS - **Yes**. you can avoid code repetition through storing the links in some form of configuration which determines if a nav link appears in the navbar, the navdropdown, or both, for example:
`navItems = [{ text: "About", href: "/about", inNavBar: false, inNavDropdown: true},...]`

One would then iterate through this array and dynamically create the two nav views

A quick JSX, for example, would be:

```
const navItems = [...] // your nav items config array

const navBar = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div class="navbar-nav ...">
      {navItems
        .filter(({ inNavBar }) => inNavBar)
        .forEach(({ text, href }) => (
          <a class="nav-item nav-link href={href}>{text}</a>)}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
)
</div>

const navDropdown = () => (
  // same as navBar() but will filter for inNavDropDown == true instead of inNavBar
)
```

A vanilla JS implementation would contain the same logic, but some verbosity and difference in the creation of the elements.

Comment: Is it possible to use flexbox ordering?

Comment: It is yes, but flex can only control layout and can reverse the order of a column/row of items. Indeed, bootstrap is just a wrapper around flex.